# Java- Runtime.getRuntime().exec() will not execute python.exe

Tags: java, runtime

For a project I need to start python.exe via Runtime.getRuntime.exec(). However, when I try to run it it won't execute, but it doesn't throw up an IOException. Here's the code:

```
try 
    {

        Process process=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\PythonTest\\python.exe");
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        System.out.println("Cannot find python.exe");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the output from the process and ([`waitFor()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor%28%29) it to finish). Something like,

```
final String cmd = "C:/Program Files (x86)/PythonTest/python.exe";
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
final InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
    int ch;
    try {
      while ((ch = isr.read()) != -1) {
        System.out.print((char) ch);
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
});
t.start();
p.waitFor();
t.join();
```

To actually do something with `python` you'll want to get the `OutputStream`.

Comment: Unless puthinnisnconfigured correctly, you may not get any out,that doesn't mean you should check for output and getting the exit code for the process would also be a good idea

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is due to `eval` incorrectly splitting the command string.  My understanding is that `exec("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\PythonTest\\python.exe")`  will attempt to run an application called `"C:\\Program"`, passing it 2 command line arguments.

Try this instead:

```
 exec(new String[]{"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\PythonTest\\python.exe"});
```

The `exec(String, ...)` command line parsing is primitive, and often has the incorrect behaviour from the programmer's perspective.  The best bet is often to split the command and arguments yourself.

Comment: I've tried this and what else was suggested and it will work for other .exe I try to execute, but still not python.exe. I don't know if it's something specific to python.exe or what.